# Parse returned record type into multiple columns in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Postgresql function which returns multiple values as record. I need to accept record type and parse as multiple columns.
I call function inside `select` statement like below:

```
SELECT bank_id, myfunction(document_id,'DF') FROM timeline_chronicle WHERE document_id = 102;
```

Above statement returns like this:

```
--------------------------------------
bank_id   |   record
----------------------------------------
9006      | (DOCUMENT_IS_ACCEPTED,"2020-07-03 16:37:28","2020-07-03 16:41:58",270)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But i need below version

```
--------------------------------------
bank_id   |   event_type         | start_time          | end_time            | difference   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
9006      | DOCUMENT_IS_ACCEPTED | 2020-07-03 16:37:28 | 2020-07-03 16:41:58 |  270
----------------------------------------
```

In addition I tried below version but anyway not working:

```
SELECT bank_id, myfunction(document_id,'DF') as (event_type text,start_time TIMESTAMP,end_time TIMESTAMP,difference integer) FROM timeline_chronicle WHERE document_id = 102;
```

Postgre Version is: **9.6.18**. My Postgre Function is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(doc_id integer,oper_name2 text) 
RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE

start_tim               timestamp(0) without time zone;
end_tim                 timestamp(0) without time zone;
event_typo              text;
tim_diff                integer;
ret                     RECORD;

BEGIN
    start_tim := (SELECT to_timestamp(MIN(created_at))::timestamp FROM table WHERE document_id = 62);
    SELECT event_type,created_at INTO event_typo,end_tim FROM (
        SELECT document_id,oper_name,event_type,to_timestamp(created_at)::timestamp as created_at, 
            case when event_type in ('DOCUMENT_IS_DENY','DOCUMENT_IS_ACCEPTED')  then 2 else 1 end as status
        FROM table  
        WHERE document_id = 62 order by created_at asc
        ) s WHERE status = 2 order by created_at asc limit 1;

    tim_diff:= (select extract(epoch from (end_tim-start_tim)));  
    SELECT event_typo,start_tim,end_tim,tim_diff INTO ret;
    RETURN ret;
   
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What data type is created_at? Why isn't that a timestamp?

Comment: In table it is ```integer``` type

Comment: The cast `::timestamp` is useless though, as `to_timestamp()` already returns a timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a typed record in order to see column names. For that you need to create a proper return type:

```
create type function_result as 
( 
  event_type text,
  start_time TIMESTAMP,
  end_time TIMESTAMP,
  difference bigint
);
```

Then in your function use:

```
return (event_typo,start_tim,end_tim,tim_diff)::function_result;
```

(no need for the `ret` variable)

Then you can expand the record in the query into columns using:

```
SELECT bank_id, (myfunction(document_id,'DF')).* 
FROM timeline_chronicle 
WHERE document_id = 102;
```

---

Note that:

```
tim_diff := (select extract(epoch from (end_tim-start_tim)));
```

can be simplified to:

```
tim_diff := extract(epoch from (end_tim-start_tim));
```